# WCF- adding authentication layer

Tags: c#, wcf, security, authentication, authorization

I have been reading a lot for the past few days about authentication and authorization in WCF and I still cant decide what is the best option in my scenario:

In our company we have a permission system, each user that would need to have access to any method in the new service will need to get a specific permission for that method.

I get the user identity from the active directory and then I send a request to the permission system to check if the user has a specific permission for the method.

My question is as follows:
**where should that check be implemented?** doing it in each method seems wrong. i want to have a layer before the method itself to inform me if the user has the needed permission or not to access the method.

help will be super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a centralize entry point for checking authorization, you can create an extended custom implementation of [ServiceAuthorizationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and reference it your WCF configuration file.

```
public class MyServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {                
        // Extract the action URI from the OperationContext. Match this against the claims
        // in the AuthorizationContext.
        string action = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.Action;

        // Iterate through the various claim sets in the AuthorizationContext.
        foreach(ClaimSet cs in operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets)
        {
            // Examine only those claim sets issued by System.
            if (cs.Issuer == ClaimSet.System)
            {
                // Iterate through claims of type "http://www.contoso.com/claims/allowedoperation".
                foreach (Claim c in cs.FindClaims("http://www.contoso.com/claims/allowedoperation", Rights.PossessProperty))
                {
                    // If the Claim resource matches the action URI then return true to allow access.
                    if (action == c.Resource.ToString())
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

      // If this point is reached, return false to deny access.
      return false;                 
    }
}
```

Adding reference in your service configuration:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Samples.MyServiceAuthorizationManager,MyAssembly" />
     </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

The above implementation will fire every time the user will access any services your have in your server.

If you want additional [Authorization Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.policy.iauthorizationpolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can also extend IAuthorizationPolicy.